# Trigger onclick from javascript-generated li a element

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jplayer

On my website, www.danielLmusic.com, in the listen section, I am trying to activate the record player arm animated gif (recordstart.gif) when an item from the j-player playlist is clicked. The difficulty is that the the playlist elements are loaded via javascript and a normal reference to .jp-playlist li a does not work. I looked around this site and found someone suggested using the `on('click','a',function(){`function, which got me 75% there, except that it only loads the gif from the *second* time the user clicks a song and not the first. I pasted the html and javascript below... Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you

```
<div class="jp-playlist">
                              <ul>
                                <li></li> <!-- Empty <li> so your HTML conforms with the W3C spec -->
                              </ul>
                            </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('.jp-playlist ul').on('click','a',function(){
       $('.jp-playlist a').click(function(){
          $('#soundsystem').css('background-image','url(graphics/recordstart.gif)');

           setTimeout(function (){ 
               $('#soundsystem').css('background-image','url(graphics/recordplaying.gif)');
           },1500);


       });
       $('a.jp-pause').click(function(){
           $('#soundsystem').css('background-image','url(graphics/recordstop.gif)');
       });
       $('a.jp-stop').click(function(){
          $('#soundsystem').css('background-image','url(graphics/recordstop.gif)');
       });
   });
});
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
try this:
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('body').on('click','.jp-playlist ul a',function(){
       $('.jp-playlist a').click(function(){
          $('#soundsystem').css('background-image','url(graphics/recordstart.gif)');

           setTimeout(function (){ 
               $('#soundsystem').css('background-image','url(graphics/recordplaying.gif)');
           },1500);


       });
       $('a.jp-pause').click(function(){
           $('#soundsystem').css('background-image','url(graphics/recordstop.gif)');
       });
       $('a.jp-stop').click(function(){
          $('#soundsystem').css('background-image','url(graphics/recordstop.gif)');
       });
   });
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Could you explain what difference it will make?

Comment: when you attach the "on" event to the body, it listens to changes made on the DOM, while when you attach the  "on" to an element that does not exist, it will trigger only after the elrmenet have been added to the dom

Comment: You still have two click listeners: `on()` delegated to the `body` inside of which is `click()` on the element itself. And btw, `on()` is a method, not event.

Comment: First, thank you for such expedient responses. Unfortunately, I tried both of those suggestions, and it's still not grabbing it. I'm not experienced enough to know exactly why, though. :-(

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. Pavlo's code worked. I just forgot to remove a set of brackets further down in my code. Thank you both for your time and help! If you wish to see the correction, it's now on www.danielLmusic.com .